# 443 port is attached to hostname for no reason

Tags: php, ssl, nginx, centos

I run a website on `https://hostname.example`
But all requests are going through `https://hostname.example:443` (a previous developer of this website tells that it should go strainght to hostname without the ssl port)

It seems that this affects a website in a bad way -- some features do not work.

For example,

[image: a post request from the starting page of a website]

Info:

CentOS 6.8.

nginx 1.10.2

ssl certificate is present and configured (not by me)

**The questions are:**

- why all requests started to go through the ssl port when they didn't do it before?
- how to tickle this problem and make all requests go just through the hostname?

Please, advise me on what else to include in the question to clarify the problem.

UPD.

```
default.conf 
#
# The default server
#

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
#    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
server_name  www.hostname.example;

return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

#root         /path/to/root;
#index index.php index.html;

# Load configuration files for the default server block.
#include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

#location ~ ^/purge(/.*) {
#    allow     127.0.0.1;
#    allow     192.168.118.10;
#    deny     all;
#    fastcgi_cache_purge portalName $request_method$http_if_modified_since$http_if_none_match$host$1;
#}

#location / {
#}

#error_page 404 /404.html;
#    location = /40x.html {
#}

#error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#    location = /50x.html {
#}

#location ~ \.php$ {
#    fastcgi_cache  portalName;
#   fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 304 60m;
#   fastcgi_cache_key "$request_method$http_if_modified_since$http_if_none_match$host$request_uri";
#   fastcgi_pass_header "X-Accel-Expires";

#        set $no_cache 0;
#        fastcgi_cache  pubcache;
#        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 304 5m;
#        fastcgi_cache_key "$request_method|$http_if_modified_since|$http_if_none_match|$host|$request_uri";
#        fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500;

#        fastcgi_pass_header Set-Cookie;
#        fastcgi_pass_header Cookie;
#        fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;

#        fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
#        fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;
#        proxy_cache_purge  PURGE from 127.0.0.1,192.168.118.10;

#    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
##   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
#    fastcgi_index index.php;
#    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
#    fastcgi_param HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH $http_if_none_match;
#    fastcgi_param HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE $http_if_modified_since;
#    fastcgi_param HTTP_X_REAL_IP $remote_addr;
#    include        fastcgi_params;
#}
}








ssl.conf
#
# HTTPS server configuration
#

server {
    listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#    listen       [::]:443 ssl;
server_name  www.hostname.example;
root         /path/to/root;
index       index.php index.html;
#
#    ssl_certificate hostname.example.crt;
#    ssl_certificate_key  hostname.example.key;
ssl_certificate hostname_example.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  hostname_example.key;

ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
ssl_session_timeout  10m;
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
location / {
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_cache  portalName;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 304 60m;
    fastcgi_cache_key "$request_method$http_if_modified_since$http_if_none_match$host$request_uri";
    fastcgi_pass_header "X-Accel-Expires";

#        set $no_cache 0;
#        fastcgi_cache  pubcache;
#        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 304 5m;
#        fastcgi_cache_key "$request_method|$http_if_modified_since|$http_if_none_match|$host|$request_uri";
#        fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500;

#        fastcgi_pass_header Set-Cookie;
#        fastcgi_pass_header Cookie;
#        fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;

#        fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
#        fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;
#        proxy_cache_purge  PURGE from 127.0.0.1,192.168.118.10;

        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH $http_if_none_match;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE $http_if_modified_since;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_X_REAL_IP $remote_addr;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

UPD_2. Well, thanks everybody for the comments. I'll go and seek the root of problems somewhere else.

Comment: whats your nginx config look like? have you searched the entire codebase for `443` or some redirect which looks for or includes proto?

Comment: Somwhere, something is forcing a redirect to that port, so do like Lawrence says and do a full search for `443`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I added config files. In the codebase there is a js code that at a first glance basically says to choose a port 80, otherwise choose 443 (but again, this contradicts with the previous developer, who wrote the code, so I might be mistaken what this code actually does...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

443 is the port for https, so it is there for a reason. A request can not go "straight to hostname" it always has to be a combination of hostname and port. Almost always the browser chooses the port based on protocol and you don't see it.

What you see in your screenshot is perfectly normal, try it with any other https-site, it will look the same.

Either you have bug somewhere else or you didn't show us the problem in your question.

Comment: It seems you has it right about http and https. Can't imagine why the developer thought it strange...